# Classes for plotting data in daily, monthly, and yearly groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code, Only difference is way it groups data, Is there any way to make this into one logic by passing group by arguments, So the duplicate code can be removed.

```
 public interface IStackChartData
 {
    IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting);
 }

 public class DailyStack : IStackChartData
 {
    public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Hour, x.RateId })
                                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                         cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                         cl.Key.Hour.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                         cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                         chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
}
}

 public class MonthlyStack : IStackChartData
 {
public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
{
    return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Date, x.RateId })
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                              cl.Key.RateId,
                                                              cl.Key.Date.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                              cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                              chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
}
}

 public class YearlyStack : IStackChartData
 {
     public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
{
    return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Month, x.RateId })
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId).Select(cl => new StackChartData(
                                                                              cl.Key.RateId,
                                                                              cl.Key.Month.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                                              cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                                                                              chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with generics and an abstract class which implements your details.  To make it generic you need to get rid of the anonymous class and use something like a Tuple.  This code wasn't tested but should give you an idea.

```
public abstract class BaseStack : IStackChartData
{

    public abstract IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting);

    protected IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> InternalGetDetails<TGroup>(StackChartSetting chartSetting,
        Func<DateTime, TGroup> groupBy, Func<TGroup, string> keyFunc)
    {
        return chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints
            .GroupBy(g => Tuple.Create(groupBy(g.DataTime), g.RateId))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Item2)
            .Select(x => new StackChartData(x.Key.Item2,
                keyFunc(x.Key.Item1),
                x.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
                chartSetting.GetColorCode(x.Key.Item2)))
            .ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

}
```

You will need to pass in a func of how you want to group by your DateTime and then another func of how you want the string version of that group.   Since the Date one also needed a different way to convert it to a string.   With this you can now base your other class on this base one

```
public class DailyStack : BaseStack
{
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return InternalGetDetails(chartSetting, dt => dt.Hour, h => h.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
}

public class MonthlyStack : BaseStack
{
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return InternalGetDetails(chartSetting, dt => dt.Date, d => d.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
}

public class YearlyStack : BaseStack
{
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting)
    {
        return InternalGetDetails(chartSetting, dt => dt.Month, m => m.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
}
```

Using a Tuple does make the code less readable so you will need to see if that is a deal breaker for you or not.  Also to me your class names seem a bit off to me.  If I was joining your project and saw a class called dailystack I wouldn't expect it group by hours and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ENUM, ho looks like:

```
    public enum StackTime{
       Hour,
       Date,
       Month
    }
```

And use this in yours method:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<StackChartData> GetDetails(StackChartSetting chartSetting, StackTime stackTime)
{
    var stackChartDataPoints = chartSetting.StackChartDataPoints;

    switch(stackTime)
    {
        case stackTime.Date:
            stackChartDataPoints = stackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Date, x.RateId });
            break;
        case stackTime.Month:
            stackChartDataPoints = stackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Month, x.RateId });
            break;
        default:
            stackChartDataPoints = stackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(x => new { x.DataTime.Hour, x.RateId });
            break;
    }

    return stackChartDataPoints.OrderBy(x => x.Key.RateId)
        .Select(cl => new StackChartData(
            cl.Key.RateId,
            cl.Key.Date.Day.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
            cl.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.YData)),
            chartSetting.GetColorCode(cl.Key.RateId))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: As I can understand you didn't test your "solution". **1)** `stackChartDataPoints = stackChartDataPoints.GroupBy(...)` will not be compiled since the types of `stackChartDataPoints` (`IEnumerable<TElement>`) and result of `GroupBy` (`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`) are different; **2)** what about `cl.Key.Date.Day` in `StackChartData` constructor? :)

Comment: No i don't test in this case, but i convinced this example, whith lite fix will work.

Comment: No i don't test in this case, but i convinced this example, whith lite fix will work.
AD1. Yes, stackChartDataPoints  must be type of IEnumerable.
AD2. I don't know what you means, I get this example from first post

Comment: Well I'll explain the point #2: if you take a look at the original post you'll notice that the second argument of `StackChartData`'s constructor is different for each stack class. But in your solution `cl.Key.Date.Day` will be used for all cases.

Comment: Ok, I don't see of this ^_^, my bad, but you can do some function ho return string or something else you think